# django + nginx in docker containers: can not upload any file with forms

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am trying to migrate my app to docker containers, but met the problem uploading files with django forms. Everything works just fine, but when I try to upload any file from forms in my app I get nothing, like `multipart/form-data`  is not set in html form tag. But it set and everythings works if I install application directly with no dockers. Anyways here is my configs, I hope somebody can help me.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2' 
services:
    db_postgres:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/docker-postgres/Dockerfile
            args:
            - db_user=username
            - db_name=databasename
            - db_pass=password
        environment:
            LC_ALL: C.UTF-8

    app:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/docker-app/Dockerfile
        links:
            - db_postgres:db_postgres

    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: dockerfiles/docker-nginx
        volumes_from:
            - app
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - app:applink
```

Here is application Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential python-virtualenv && \
  apt-get install -y libjpeg8 libjpeg62-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev && \
  apt-get install -y libpq-dev libffi-dev && \
  apt-get install -y libssl-dev git 

RUN mkdir app
COPY requrements.txt /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requrements.txt
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME ["/app/staticfiles/", "/app/media/", "/app/protected/"]
# I tried this but it seams no effect at all
# this is media folders where users can upload their files
# nginx can read from this folders with no problem
# I tried to docker exec and nginx can even write there
# anyways I tried to start nginx as root
RUN chown www-data:www-data -R /app/media/
RUN chown www-data:www-data -R /app/protected/    

ADD dockerfiles/docker-app/django_entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x django_entrypoint.sh  
CMD ["./django_entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

Here is django_entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=my_app_name
USER=www-data
GROUP=www-data
NUM_WORKERS=8
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=my_application.wsgi

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
echo "Collenting staticfiles..."
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput > /dev/null
python manage.py initadmin
python manage.py init_default_settings
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=:8000 \
  --log-level=debug \
  --capture-output
```

here is nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# Install Nginx.
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y nginx && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-available", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d"]
ADD confgfile /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ctrd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ctrd
# Define default command.
CMD ["nginx"]
# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Here is configfile for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # I pasted my server ip in sever name
    server_name 175.116.110.231;
    client_max_body_size 300M;

    error_log stdout debug;
    location /static/ {
        alias   /app/staticfiles/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias   /app/media/;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-FILE $request_body_file;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://applink:8000;
    }

    location /private-uploads/ {
        internal;
        alias /app/protected/records/;
    }

}
```

The app works fine, but when I want to upload any file it does nothing, no file, no errors in errorlogs. If filefield can not be empty (requred=True in django forms), I got the error about that. 
In request in broswer tools:

```
Request URL:http://175.116.110.231/edit-avatar/2
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:175.116.110.231:80
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Language:ru
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 19 Sep 2016 13:26:59 GMT
Location:/profile/
Server:nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Language, Cookie
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:30316
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySCXVqlqPsCHyaHtU
Cookie:JSESSIONID=dummy; sessionid=htnbd9coal4ws2ansxzze8bhtu4fq6do; csrftoken=tCD5cVrR0IUGkjkkbJKDsxdRrtyLIUGbOIHkjHKjhkjhmnVJhvKUGkBDjZ
DNT:1
Host:175.116.110.231
Origin:http://175.116.110.231
Referer:http://175.116.110.231/edit-avatar/2
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.90 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.4.589.11
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarySCXVqlqPsCHyaHtU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

zaAvb1KoCCovbuCbik261UDeZgQbJdumzcvpcqOHqTKIrRN826lEoeb5AvU7SrG6
------WebKitFormBoundarySCXVqlqPsCHyaHtU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="ava2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarySCXVqlqPsCHyaHtU--
```

Upd gunicorn debug output at startup:

```
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
ctrd_app_1      |   secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
ctrd_app_1      |   proxy_protocol: False
ctrd_app_1      |   worker_connections: 1000
ctrd_app_1      |   statsd_host: None
ctrd_app_1      |   max_requests_jitter: 0
ctrd_app_1      |   post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x7fb7e74ee230>
ctrd_app_1      |   pythonpath: None
ctrd_app_1      |   enable_stdio_inheritance: False
ctrd_app_1      |   worker_class: sync
ctrd_app_1      |   ssl_version: 3
ctrd_app_1      |   suppress_ragged_eofs: True
ctrd_app_1      |   syslog: False
ctrd_app_1      |   syslog_facility: user
ctrd_app_1      |   when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x7fb7e74e5ed8>
ctrd_app_1      |   pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x7fb7e74ee0c8>
ctrd_app_1      |   cert_reqs: 0
ctrd_app_1      |   preload_app: False
ctrd_app_1      |   keepalive: 2
ctrd_app_1      |   accesslog: None
ctrd_app_1      |   group: 33
ctrd_app_1      |   graceful_timeout: 30
ctrd_app_1      |   do_handshake_on_connect: False
ctrd_app_1      |   spew: False
ctrd_app_1      |   workers: 8
ctrd_app_1      |   proc_name: django_ctrd_app
ctrd_app_1      |   sendfile: None
ctrd_app_1      |   pidfile: None
ctrd_app_1      |   umask: 0
ctrd_app_1      |   on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x7fb7e74e5d70>
ctrd_app_1      |   pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x7fb7e74ee7d0>
ctrd_app_1      |   worker_tmp_dir: None
ctrd_app_1      |   post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x7fb7e74ee398>
ctrd_app_1      |   limit_request_fields: 100
ctrd_app_1      |   on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x7fb7e74eee60>
ctrd_app_1      |   config: None
ctrd_app_1      |   logconfig: None
ctrd_app_1      |   check_config: False
ctrd_app_1      |   statsd_prefix: 
ctrd_app_1      |   proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
ctrd_app_1      |   pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x7fb7e74ee938>
ctrd_app_1      |   post_request: <function post_request at 0x7fb7e74eea28>
ctrd_app_1      |   user: 33
ctrd_app_1      |   forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
ctrd_app_1      |   worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x7fb7e74ee500>
ctrd_app_1      |   threads: 1
ctrd_app_1      |   max_requests: 0
ctrd_app_1      |   limit_request_line: 4094
ctrd_app_1      |   access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
ctrd_app_1      |   certfile: None
ctrd_app_1      |   worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x7fb7e74eeb90>
ctrd_app_1      |   chdir: /app
ctrd_app_1      |   paste: None
ctrd_app_1      |   default_proc_name: calltrade.wsgi:application
ctrd_app_1      |   errorlog: -
ctrd_app_1      |   loglevel: debug
ctrd_app_1      |   capture_output: True
ctrd_app_1      |   syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
ctrd_app_1      |   syslog_prefix: None
ctrd_app_1      |   daemon: False
ctrd_app_1      |   ciphers: TLSv1
ctrd_app_1      |   on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x7fb7e74e5c08>
ctrd_app_1      |   worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x7fb7e74ee668>
ctrd_app_1      |   bind: [':8000']
ctrd_app_1      |   raw_env: []
ctrd_app_1      |   reload: False
ctrd_app_1      |   limit_request_field_size: 8190
ctrd_app_1      |   nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x7fb7e74eecf8>
ctrd_app_1      |   timeout: 30
ctrd_app_1      |   ca_certs: None
ctrd_app_1      |   django_settings: None
ctrd_app_1      |   tmp_upload_dir: None
ctrd_app_1      |   keyfile: None
ctrd_app_1      |   backlog: 2048
ctrd_app_1      |   logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [38] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 38
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [39] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 39
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [44] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 44
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [47] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 47
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [48] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [51] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 51
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:47 +0000] [54] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 54
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:48 +0000] [59] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 59
ctrd_app_1      | [2016-09-19 16:33:48 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 8 workers
```

I also tried 8000:8000  port expose on gunicorn container and It also can not save file, so the reason is not nginx, but my bad configuration of docker volumes maybe. Can someone explain docker volumes? PLease check my config of volumes, I must be do not understand how it should work.
Please help.

Here is media serving view:

```
@login_required
def private_media_response(request, username, filename):
    """
    In the nginx setting we can use something like here:
    location /private-uploads/ {
        internal;
        alias /place/to/private/media/;
    }
    """
    user = request.user
    if user.username == username:
        response = HttpResponse()
        url = '/private-uploads/{0}/{1}'.format(username, filename)
        response.status_code = 200
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url.encode('utf-8')
        response['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'yes'
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden("Restricted Access")
```

The problem is not to get the file, I can not save it with forms.
All my views that saving files looks like model update CBV or this standart view:

```
@login_requred
def file_save_view(request, **kwags):
    if request.POST:
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid()
            form.save()
    else:
        form = myForm();
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form':form})
```

Standart models save file data in media, for protected files I create `FileSystemStorage`

```
location = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'protected')
fs = FileSystemStorage(location=location)
```

and then use it in models:

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    user = instance.user
    return 'documents/{0}/{1}'.format(user, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document = models.FileField(
        upload_to=get_upload_path,
        storage=fs,
    )
    pass
```

This code little bit abstract, but it works on standart deploy way. Must be something wrong with volumes I guess.

Comment: If I try to save unsupported type of file  - I got message about it in form errors message, then django can see that file, but for some reason can not save it? Maybe I made smething wrong with volumes, how should I save media files with docker?

Comment: Why do you think the issue has anything to do with Docker or nginx or anything other than the actual code that handles the file processing... which is the only thing you didn't include?

Comment: Because the code work fine if I deploy application to single server, just nginx + django + gunicorn on the host. And there is no anything special in the code, just some class based view, updating the model with filefield on it.  I do not sure 100% anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you do seem to misunderstand volumes to some extent (though I don't see anything that would cause your problem).

Volumes come from the "copy on write" filesystem that Docker uses for its images.  Each layer only contains new information that hasn't been changed since previous uses- this lets you build images in an efficient fashion without having to copy tons of data around for each container you start off of that image.

A volume is saying "do not use the copy on write filesystem for this directory".  So `VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-available", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d"]` is actually telling Docker to leave those directories OUT of the image you build.  This is not what you want... I see you adding config files to your nginx configuration AFTER marking the config directory as a volume... those files changes will not propogate into the image you are building.

On to your actual problem though- I have no idea what that is.  None of the deployment configuration has anything to do with "saving a file".  The only place it could is if you were trying to save it from django and then serve it back up with nginx... but you said the file isn't getting saved, which means that nginx has nothing to do with it.  I would add some debug output to your app itself to try and figure out what is going on.  If it is returning a 200 without doing what it says it is (saving some file to disk)... that is where I would start.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I am going to learn more documentation about volumes and thanks for your notes, they help me understand more. I will try to play with volumes and will post the result here.

Comment: The code is Class Based Updateview, its just updating some model with filefield. It works without docker. I found that the file come till the django app, because django can serv its type and size. It seams it have no permission to write it on the disk, but I have no any report in logs about it, and need debug it deeper. Can docker volumes somehow override the place where the file should be saved?

Comment: You didn't provide the code, so this is a random guess... does the directory not exist?  you create `/app/protected/` in the Dockerfile, but nginx is trying to read from `/app/protected/records`...

Comment: Yes because this is protected file they should serve by view which check permission on file and return  nginx 'X-Accel-Redirect' responce to serve internal requests. But this is not only place where file saving do not work, there are many places with standart views that save and read media images from /media/ directory.  I added that private media serving view in my first message.

Comment: Yes the directories exist, and I can see common files in them when docker exec to container with that volumes. I can create any file in there, and after the restarting conainers, files still there. I do not understand something: If I create volume from app containted ( forexample /media/) with no mounting it on host, can I save files there? Where in dockersystem should I hold users media files? Should I make volumes at the end of dockerfile?

Comment: I'm sorry, your problem is going to be something impossible to troubleshoot with the limited info available.  Troubleshooting steps... 1.  is django getting the file?  2.  does django think it saved the file?  3.  where did django try to save the file?  4.  what is actually in that location?  Good luck...

Comment: 1.I dont sure, but it is react on large file size then yes, it know about file.
2.Dont think so, If yes django would change url in database for filefield
3.In MEDIA_ROOT + path, which mounted as named volume to app and nginx. I checked from both containers, it is accessible and writeable. If create any file manually both can see it and read it
4.It is empty location and I want to mount it to store users files, and sharing the data between wsgi and nginx. Another container for static, and I populate it with COPY in Dockerfile. Static works fine. How people store uploaded files with docker?

Comment: OMG! I tried again to just add simplest template + model + form and it worked! I hate myself now! So docker configured correctly but error still there.

Comment: My suggestion wasn't to answer those questions- it was to go and add print statements to your code to find out exactly what is going in there that is different from what you THINK is going on in there :)

Comment: I found a problem will post it  in a couple minutes, yes you are right :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123873/discussion-between-grayson-hunt-and-paul-becotte).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in very strange place for me.

there are model:

```
class Document(Model):
    name = CharField()
    file = ImageField(
                upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/',
                default='default.doc'
            )
```

If I delete `default` here, it works! But version with default work fine outside the docker.

Comment: very weird... I am facing similar issue where wagtail file upload don't work but django admin ones do.